# Microsoft Graph API Get all Permissions for library

Tags: .net, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I am trying to get all the permissions list for the library. But it looks different from what I see on UI part and what I retrieve using Microsoft Graph.

```
 var permissions = graphClient.Drives[drive.Id].Root.Permissions.Request().GetAsync();
```

It returns a list of permissions. But for the library, we have users and groups who has "Limited access".

[image]

If i will loop for each item in the library and take permissions for each of them in a result list will be not full also.
Do someone know how solved it?

Comment: Can you please share/translate what error that you're noticing above?

Comment: For example, using UI  shows 2 groups and 1 user. When i use Graph API it returns all this data + several users with permissions "owner". If in UI i will go to the link in picture "Show users which have limited access". UI shows me  14 groups/users most of them has Permission level is  "Limited access". But Graph Api will not give this list. only user whish have owner, read, write permissions but no ones from this list with  "limited access"

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you will not be able to get the permissions at higher level - you will have to go through each item and get a unique permission at the item level and then gather the list.

You mentioned that , you may not be able to get the full list - I could think of edge that will cause this.

```
/sites/{siteId}/drive/items/{itemId}/permissions
```

Alternatively, if you like to know all the users - at the site level - you can query the User information list using the Sharepoint ReST API.

```
   _api/Web/lists/getbytitle('User Information List')/getitems
```

You could filter for all active users - this will not provide the permisssions possesed by them  - but gives a list of users added to the site.